# D3.js Force Layout - showing only part of a graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, force-layout

Good morning,

just starting with the awesome d3js library ...

I want to show only a portion of a graph with the force directed layout. The idea is to have one node declared as the "center" and show all nodes within a distance of two (for example) from this center node, the neighbors of the center node and the neighbors of the neighbors.  If the user clicks on one of the displayed nodes it becomes the "new" center node and a different "subgraph" is displayed. I wonder if there is an example around implementing this kind of subgraph layout and if some kind of a "node-distance" algorithm is already implemented in d3js.

Thanks a lot

martin

UPDATE:
Just found the example [Modifying a Force Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) which illuminates how to add and remove nodes and edges from a force directed layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just uploaded a "proof of concept level" of an interactive force directed subgraph.

http://justdharma.com/d3/sub-graph/

In this example I use backbonejs under the hood. Being the first time I implement something with backbonejs, I for sure use it in a very crude manner. While this example might illuminate one way how an interactive sub-graph can be achieved it is for sure not a template how to do it - as said just a proof of concept hack ...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't implemented in D3, and I'm not aware of any examples. What you would have to do is the following:

- Set the `fixed` attribute of the new center node to true to prevent the force layout from changing its position.
- Set the `px` and `py` attributes of that same node to the center position.
- For each node in your force layout, compute the shortest path to the new center node.
- Depending on the length of the path in each case, either remove the node or keep it.

The trickiest part here is the computation of the path from each node to the new center, but even this is a pretty standard algorithmic problem. Another thing to keep in mind is that you need to modify the data structures that contain the nodes and links of the force layout in place, i.e. you can't set new nodes and links for the force layout and expect everything to work smoothly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am just about to implement it and - as beginner - struggle to understand the underlying data structure but that is part of the game anyway. The shorted path seems a quite straight forward recursion and I am kind of familiar with it from prefuse/flare. I will share if something meaningful comes out of it and let this question open for a while as somebody else might have some additional insights on it. Thanks again for your answer.